# What impact does the factorization of a polynomial have on the degree of its remainder?

Tags: polynomials

Given polynomials $A(x,y,z)$ $B(x,y,z)$ and $C(x,y,z)$ with integer coefficients if the following relation holds

$$AB=A(xy,yz,zx)+C(x,y,z)$$
Then is the degree of the polynomial $C$ less than the degree of polynomial $A$?

The way I tried to argue for this claim is as follows: We can rewrite the above relation as $$A(xy,yz,zx)=AB-C.$$ Notice that this form suggests that $-C$ is the remainder obtained when $A|A(xy,yz,zx).$ I read on this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) that the degree of remainder must be less than that of $A$ and thus, I concluded that $\deg C<\deg A$. However I am not sure whether this would be true for multivariate polynomials like the ones involved in this problem and therefore I would like someone to either provide counter-examples or provide hints required to prove the claim (if it is true.)

Comment: If $A$ is allowed to be a constant, then solutions are easily found of polynomial $C$ having strictly greater degree.  For example, letting $A=1$ we get simply $B = 33C + 1$, and $C$ could be any polynomial.

Comment: @hardmath please read the edited question.

Comment: Your rewrite omits the curious factor $33$ in the original version.  That said, if you mean to avoid $A$ having degree zero, you should mention that.

Comment: Sure! But what do you think about this problem?

Comment: I've already shown that $C $ can have arbitrarily high degree if $A $ constant is allowed.   I  can give more interesting examples if you are done revising the Question.

Answer (score 1):

The appeal to the Division Algorithm/Remainder Theorem is misplaced in that the degree (or other norm) of the remainder being strictly smaller than that of the divisor is a condition *imposed* to make the remainder unique (when the Division Algorithm is carried out).

The expression:

$$ A(xy,yz,zx) = AB - C $$

does not imply that polynomial $C$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$ will have degree less than polynomial $A$.  Let's begin by exhibiting a family of counterexamples.

Suppose that $A$ divides $A(xy,yz,zx)$, say:

$$ A(xy,yz,zx) = AD $$

for some polynomial factor $D \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$.  One case of this was already mentioned when $A$ is constant, so that $D=1$ is such a factor.

A less trivial case is $A = xyz$, so that $A(xy,yz,zx) = A^2$.  In any case it is possible that $A$ will be a proper divisor of $A(xy,yz,zx)$.

Now consider $A(xy,yz,zx) = A^2 = A(D+E) - AE$ for any polynomial $E$ whatsoever.  Thus $C = AE$ can have arbitrarily high degree, higher certainly than whatever fixed degree $A$ may have.

This sort of thing already applies in the arithmetic of integers, so using multivariate polynomials is not the source of this particular phenomenon.  That is, suppose the division algorithm is carried out with the result:

$$ m = ad + r $$

where we *choose* the remainder $r$ so that $0 \le r \lt |a|$.  The above equation can then be rewritten:

$$ m = a(d - e) + (r+ae) $$

using whatever "error" term $e$ we like.  Thus the appearance of $r+e$ in the same position as a remainder does not guarantee its smallness.  Rather $r$ is chosen to be the smallest possible (nonnegative) remainder (in one version of the division algorithm).

---

Which brings us to a more restricted (and hence plausible) version of the problem.  That is, among the various expressions:

$$ A(xy, yz, zx) = AB - C $$

will there always be one in which degree $C$ is less than degree $A$?

Since positive degrees are finite, it is of course true that there is a minimum degree of the possible $C$ which appears in such an expression.  In the cases described above with $A(xy,yz,zx)$ divisible by $A$, it is thus possible to take $C=0$, so that (by some approaches) one attains degree $-\infty$.

There is interest therefore in cases where $A(xy,yz,zx)$ is *not* divisible by $A$.  How much can we expect to reduce the degree of $A(xy,yz,zx)$ in that case by subtracting a multiple $AB$?

Consider as an example $A = x+y+z$, so that $A(xy,yz,zx) = xy+yz+zx$.  If it were possible to write $A(xy,yz,zx) = AB - C$ in such a way that degree $C$ were less than degree $A$, it would have to be a constant.  In fact the only possible candidate for such a constant is zero, since evaluation at $x=y=z=0$ gives us $C=0$.  That would in turn imply that $A$ divides $A(xy,yz,zx)$.

But it is not true that $A=x+y+z$ divides $A(xy,yz,zx)$ (as we deliberately chose).  If it were so, then every place where $A$ is zero, also $A(xy,yz,zx)$ would necessarily be zero.  But $A$ is zero when $x=1,y=0,z=-1$, while at that same place:

$$ A(xy,yz,zx) = A(0,0,-1) = 0 + 0 - 1 = -1 $$

Of course we can write $A(xy,yz,zx) = AB - C$ by setting $B=0$ and $C = -A(xy,yz,zx)$.  In that case degree $C$ is $2$.  We leave it as an exercise for the interested Reader to determine whether that is the minimum possible degree for $C$.